# How to resolve "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update, foreign-keys

I am trying to update child table without changing the parent table. Exactly i have parent table Album with id-album , name and so on. Then i have Song table with id-song , id-album which is foreign key references table Album , then column name and so on. For example i have 2 songs on the same album: song1 and song2 what i want to do is to kick out song from the album.

First of all is is somehow possible to do and if it is i would like to hear your suggestions. I have tried to update that row in database as well is in the tableView in javafx what i didn't mention before. Keep in mind that if that was the last song on that album i need to delete that album cause the conditions are such taht album would exists only if there is at least one song on it.

If you need some more information i will upload some code, info or classes.
Thanks in advance.

These are the queries for creating the tables.

```
 private void createTableAlbum() throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = conect.createStatement();
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS album("
            + "id_album INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            + "album_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,"
            + "no_hours smallint NOT NULL,"
            + "publishing_year date NOT NULL,"
            + "PRIMARY KEY(id_album));";

    statement.execute(query);
}

private void createTableSong() throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = conect.createStatement();
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS song("
            + "id_song INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            + "id_album INT,"
            + "song_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,"
            + "song_time smallint NOT NULL,"
            + "number_on_album smallint,"
            + "PRIMARY KEY(id_song),"
            + "FOREIGN KEY (id_album) REFERENCES album(id_album) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION);";
    statement.execute(query);
}


public void updateSong(Song song, Album album) throws SQLException {
    conect = db.openConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = conect.prepareStatement("UPDATE song"
            + " SET id_album = ?, song_name = ?, song_time = ?, number_on_album = ? WHERE id_song = ?;");
    statement.setInt(1, album.getAlbumId());
    statement.setString(2, song.getSongName());
    statement.setShort(3, song.getSongTime());
    statement.setShort(4, song.getNumberOnAlbum());
    statement.setInt(5, song.getSongId());
    statement.executeUpdate();
    db.closeConnection();
}
```

I have tried something like this but the what it does is that it deletes that particular song from the database and it is trowing the constraint error which i have put down below . The error line is here

pesmicaDao.updatePesmica(newPesmica);

```
 Pesmica currentSong = tablePesmica.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

            if (currentSong == null) {
                alert1.setContentText("You have to select row first");
                alert1.showAndWait();
            } else {

                Album album = new Album();
                album.setId_album(0);
                short serialNumberOnAlbum = 0;
                Pesmica newPesmica = new Pesmica(album, currentSong.getNaziv_pesme(), currentSong.getTrajanje(), serialNumberOnAlbum);
                newPesmica.setId_pesme(currentSong.getId_pesme());

                try {
                    pesmicaDao.updatePesmica(newPesmica);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                int i = pesmica.indexOf(currentSong);
                pesmica.removeAll(currentSong);
                pesmica.add(i, newPesmica);
                tablePesmica.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

The error code looks like :

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projekatbaze`.`pesmica`, CONSTRAINT `pesmica_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_album`) REFERENCES `album` (`id_album`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
at Dao.classes.PesmicaDAO.updatePesmica(PesmicaDAO.java:49)
at Paneli.PregledPesamaPanel.lambda$start$6(PregledPesamaPanel.java:442)
```

Solution :

I find some useful advice here so first of all let me thank you, i appreciate that. 
Well now i will update my post with the answer so that someone who has the similar problem can find this post useful.

```
public void updateSong(Song s) throws SQLException {
    conect = db.openConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = conect.prepareStatement("UPDATE song"
            + " SET id_album = ?, naziv_pesme = ?, trajanje = ?, rb_na_albumu = ? WHERE id_song = ?;");
    if (s.getAlbum().getId_album() == 0) {
        statement = conect.prepareStatement("UPDATE song"
                + " SET id_album = null, naziv_pesme = ?, trajanje = ?, rb_na_albumu = null WHERE id_song = ?;");
        statement.setString(1, s.getNaziv_pesme());
        statement.setShort(2, s.getTrajanje());
        statement.setInt(3, s.getId_song());
    } else {
        statement.setInt(1, s.getAlbum().getId_album());
        statement.setString(2, s.getNaziv_pesme());
        statement.setShort(3, s.getTrajanje());
        statement.setShort(4, s.getRb_na_albumu());
        statement.setInt(5, s.getId_song());
    }
    statement.executeUpdate();
    db.closeConnection();
}
```

Comment: Yes, please add the relevant code lines. And what exactly did not work for you and why?

Comment: No problem just a few minutes needed also, maybe some code isn't on English because English isn't mine primary language.

Comment: Clarify your question. E.g. I have no idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MilosVulic I understand, english isn't your primary language, and even we don't expect to write long sentence, and would be nice if you write something very specific. Like what are you trying to achieve and what error/exception are you getting

Comment: @juergend Well i will try to give you a better explanation. I am trying to remove the song from the album. Exactly i am trying to modify the foreign key id-album in the song table. Lets give you a simple example if i have 2 songs on one album all i want to do is to let the user to kick off the song from the album, In real life i ma trying to let the user to make a single i mean song not always need to be on the album

Comment: @Ravi i have replied to one person in the comment so you can read my answer , by the way now i will post the code where exactly i am trying to update that row.

Comment: @BranislavLazic I dont know if its allowed on Serbian, but it will be much clearer.

Comment: @MilosVulic But, we are still not clear, whether your question is related to getting unexpected output or any error ?

Comment: @Ravi Okey well when i try to update that row or kick off the song from the album, i need to set the id-album in the song table to null. that why song is not on the album and if it is last song on that album i need to delete that album from the table album.

Comment: @MilosVulic I will put it this way, you wanted to delete the songs from songs table, but if it is last songs of specific album, then you should also delete the related album. right ? As of now, you aren't getting exception/error, but you were unable to achieve this. Am I right ?

Comment: @Ravi Yes that is exactly like you have described. I can much more clarify my question and my problem if we exchange few mails.

Comment: @Ravi by the way i have a solution for the album problem but first help me to fix this problem , i have edited the question and the code, ask if you need something more.

Comment: @MilosVulic Exactly, this is what, we were expecting.. ?? You have updated your question with exception. Now, this will help us to answer your question

Comment: @Ravi As i said if you need something more i can give you but that's all the code that is in relation to this problem. I mean i can give you the pictures of runned javafx application and you can nicely see what is happening but that is only possible if we exchange the emails but i think that is not necessary.

Comment: @MilosVulic I have posted my answer, please go through it and let me know, if you have specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I found solution, but I don't have whole source code so I'm not sure if it is this that makes your problem.

Problem is that you set id_album to 0 when you call `album.setId_album(0);`

Then when you try to update row you don't have any album with id 0 which causes problem, instead when updating with 0 you can do check if that value is 0 and set id_album inside prepared statement to null(because int can't be null in java), something like this:

```
 if (p.getAlbum().getId_album() == 0) {
  // set id_album value inside statement to null
    statement = conect.prepareStatement("UPDATE song"
        + " SET id_album = null, song_name = ?, song_time = ?, number_on_album = ? WHERE id_song = ?;");
}
```

**EDIT:**
 I forgot to say you still need to set other values accordingly, there is also probably cleaner way to do it but just try to see if this is the thing that is causing problem.

Comment: Okey i undestand what you meant, let me try some modification and then I will replay to you.

Comment: Thank you, your post helped me to create the solution. The problem was exactly with the zero id.

Answer (score 1):

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot add or update a child row:...

First of all, you need to understand, why are you getting above exception and per documentation of **[NO ACTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)**,

> ... In MySQL, equivalent to
>   RESTRICT. The ***MySQL Server rejects the delete or update operation for
>   the parent table if there is a related foreign key value in the
>   referenced table***

So, you can't update parent table, if there is reference used in child table and vice-verse, and you can't update child table to the reference, which doesn't exist in parent table.

For example :

```
SET id_album = ?, ...
```

And, since you have specified below when creating songs table. So, you are getting exception.

```
FOREIGN KEY (id_album) REFERENCES album(id_album) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Because, `id_album` is foreign key in `songs` table and primary key in `album`.

**==Update==**

Since, you wanted to remove songs from `songs` table and if it is last song of specific album, then delete from album as well.

There might be multiple ways to achieve this. One of the possible way to first check  the number of songs for specific album in `songs` table. If it is greater than one then, delete the specific song from `songs` table `else` perform `delete` on `album` table, which is automatically (`CASCADE`) delete from `songs` table as well.

IMO, nullifying the `id_album` in `songs` can't be a solution, instead it will make table more dirty as most of the data won't have reference instead you should delete them.

Comment: Thank you @Ravi for you consideration and your time spent but it doesn't helped me. Even if i change ON UPDATE CASCADE .The things wont change.

Comment: @MilosVulic No, you didn't understand, problem won't solve by changing `NO ACTION` to `CASCADE`. You **CAN NOT** update the reference. Let me know, if you still have any question

Comment: That is what i have asked at the top of this question. I just need the answer is it possible to change the foreign key in child table without affecting the parent table. An example was my problem. How to remove the song from the album ,that's all. So you said it is not possible and its okey, that is the answer i can except but i am looking for the answer to resolve my problem.

Comment: @MilosVulic I will update my post with what you are suppose to do. Please note, I can't write the code. But I will tell you the logic.

Comment: @MilosVulic I have updated my post, as I mentioned I can't code, but tell you what exactly you should do.

Comment: @Ravi I understand that nullifying isn't perfect solution but considering his table design I suppose that he wants to have some songs that have album and some "solo" songs without it. Another solution would be to have 1 entry in table albums which would act as "no album" entry.

Comment: @FilipRistic I really don't find any reference where OP mentioned "solo" songs instead he mentioned *kick out song from the album*

Comment: @Ravi you see his songs table? Foreign key is set as nullable, this is just what I suppose of course OP must clarify this.

Comment: @Ravi thank you for you answer i will up vote this answer because all that you have said is true.

Comment: @FilipRistic i'm not going to argue further, but that is not null.

Comment: @MilosVulic Just make a note, what I said. Try to follow proper design else you will face lot of issue at later stage. Rest is upto you.

Comment: @Ravi  yes i wanted to have solo songs as well as the songs on albums. I have edited the post with the solution by the way. And i will try to improve my design.

Comment: @MilosVulic One more suggestion : don't post your solution in your question and try to minimize your original question with specific details. This will help reader to understand the actual issue. He/she doesn't have to put more time to understand your question

Comment: @Ravi I don't try to argue either, also I said here as well as in my solution that this isn't perfect solution but to try to do it this way in other to see if that 0 is cause of his problem.